# Performance improvement of a RandomAccessBuffer

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, optimization, profiling

I use a pdf library to convert PDF to images. This process needs a lot of time and I took a [profiler](http://visualvm.java.net/) to find the cause of the problem and it all came down (>60% CPU time) one method. Now my question is:

**Can this method be further improved?**

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {

    if (buf==null) throw new IOException("Data buffer not initialized.");

    if (pointer<0 || pointer>=length)
        return -1;

    int length=this.length-(int)pointer;
    if(length>b.length)
            length=b.length;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        buf.seek(pointer++);
        b[i] = buf.readByte();
    }
    return length;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the pdf file as a RandomAccessFile? I don't see any advantage in the additional layer introduced by RandomAccessMemoryMapBuffer.

Comment: Exactly! I thought the same - why not use RandomAccessFile. But when you look at the sourcecode this seems symptomatic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading one byte at a time in a loop (as well as performing a useless `seek()`). That's not smart, since there is a `read(byte[] b)` method in `RandomAccessFile` as well.

Change this

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    buf.seek(pointer++);
    b[i] = buf.readByte();
}
```

to

```
buf.seek(pointer);
buf.read(b);
pointer += b.length;
```